Why does logging QueueHandler still locks on handling a record?
So QueueHandler in logging.handlers is there for dedicating logs to a separate thread. It uses Queue to enqueue records in it so the consumer (QueueListener) then handles them with actual handlers. Queue itself is already thread safe and can be used without locks.
But QueueHandler class doesn't implement .handle method on class so it's inherited from logging.handlers.Handler which just checks if the handler matches filters and then locks and emits the record via .emit (which is implemented on QueueHandler).
So my question is why haven't they implemented a method on QueueHandler not to lock on every .handle? Because it's one of the reasons we use QueueHandler - to not lock the main thread with unnecessary stuff on every log line.
Original method is:
def handle(self, record):
    rv = self.filter(record)
    if rv:
        self.acquire()
        try:
            self.emit(record)
        finally:
            self.release()
    return rv

I've done something like this:
class MyQueueHandler(QueueHandler):
    def handle(self, record):
        rv = self.filter(record)
        if rv:
            self.emit(record)
        return rv

But I'm worried I'm lacking some knowledge about it and I've made a mistake.
Please help me to understand:)
